# How to make two running command-prompt windows send commands to each other on the same computer?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7, command-prompt

I am somewhat new to using the command-prompt for programming related purposes so if this makes no sense or seems unclear please request that I elaborate and I will do my best.

What I am hoping to be able to do is have two command-prompt windows open on my windows machine (running Windows 7) and have them communicate with each other. For instance I want Cmd window A to tell Cmd window B to print the contents of a file and vice versa.

Is this in anyway possible? Also, I know there may be a way to do this by polling a file in one Command-prompt window, but I would like an asynchronous/non-blocking way of doing this if it is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ohhh, using `cmd.exe` in Windows? Sorry I can't help. I assumed this was a Linux/Unix Q at first. There you would use `mkfifo` and structure a script to read input from the `fifo` file created. I would add a Powershell tag to your question. There is probably some PS guru who can help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response shellter. So do you know a way of doing this on windows using powershell? I would prefer if I could stick with the regular prompt as I am afraid that powershell may have some quirks/gotchas of its own. The regular prompt does just about everything I want except for this feature I am looking for.

Comment: Why do you think polling (every 1 second, for example) a file would block anything?

Answer (score 2):

I found it quite simple to make two command windows interact with each other.

Batch file 1:

```
:keepsending
set /p message=
Echo set run=%message% >command.bat
goto :keepsending
```

Batch file 2:

```
:running
%run%
set ran=%run%
:check
if not "%ran%"=="%run%" goto :running
call command.bat
timeout 1 >nul
goto :check
```

Add in a counter on it and i would guess you could make it work in a longer code that interacts with each other.

If you want it to work over your network then use poshd/popd

Answer (score 0):

The only way of interaction of 2 cmd windows is to call one from another from a batch file. You can pass variables from one to another.

E.g. you can set a variable in one batch and then call the second one from the first passing a variable as an input parameter.
here is an example when I determine SID value for user user first and then pass it to the script for running it to patch the computer remotely.

```
@echo off
setlocal
echo.
:entercname
set /p cname=Please enter computer name or IP address: 
if not defined cname goto entercname
echo.
FOR /F %%a IN ('psgetsid \\%cname% %uname% /accepteula') DO set sid=%%a
echo %uname%'s SID is %sid%
echo.

start /wait cmd /c c:\temp\run_lync_fix.bat %sid%
```

What I have in the second batch that I run from the first one is:

```
@echo off
set sid=%1
echo SID is %sid%
REG ADD HKU\%sid%\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator /v GalDownloadInitialDelay /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD HKU\%sid%\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync /v GalDownloadInitialDelay /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator /v GalDownloadInitialDelay /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo Registry patched.) ELSE (Echo Error. Registry not patched.)
ping -n 5 localhost > nul
```

So I pass %sid% from first batch and second one accepts it via set sid=%1.

The second tip is to store some variable to a temp or txt file in one batch and to read from it in another batch.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render" > c:\temp\reg.txt
for /f %%a in ('find /c /v "" ^< "c:\temp\reg.txt"') do set count=%%a
echo Number of lines: !count!
for /l %%i in (2,1,!count!) do (
echo Current line is: %%i
for /f "tokens=2 delims=]" %%b in ('find /n /v "" ^< "c:\temp\reg.txt" ^| findstr "^\[%%i\]"') do set test=%%b
set regstring=!test!^\Properties
echo !regstring!
for /f "tokens=3*" %%c in ('reg query !regstring! ^/v "{a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0},2"') do set value=%%c %%d
echo !value!
)
```

This code stores a set of registry subkeys from a specific key to reg.txt.
Then we read this file line by line in for /l cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: %1 supplied to routine specifies the instance name
SET "myname=%1"
:: A communications area...
SET "flagdir=U:\comms"
:: Log this instance in - file "name.run"
ECHO.>"%flagdir%\%myname%.run"
:: grab hundredths-of-seconds to modify %random%
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=." %%a IN ("%time%") DO SET /a randmod=1%%a-100
:: record of other-instances-found
SET "othero="

:: Loop runs about every second

:loop
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL
:: If the file "quit" exists, terminate
IF EXIST "%flagdir%\quit" GOTO endrun
:: look for others
SET "others="
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir/b "%flagdir%\*.run"') DO IF /i %%~na neq %myname% SET "others=!others! %%~na"
:: Report if changed
IF "%othero%" neq "%others%" CALL :report "I see %others% now"
SET "othero=%others%"
:: 2% chance of doing something...
SET /a selection=(%randmod% + (%RANDOM% %% 100)) %% 100
ECHO %selection%
IF %selection%==37 (CALL :instruct count) ELSE IF %selection%==51 (CALL :instruct repeat)
:: Do I have any instructions?
IF NOT EXIST "%flagdir%\*.%myname%" GOTO loop
:: I've been sent instructions
FOR %%i IN ("%flagdir%\*.%myname%") DO (
 SET /p instruction=<"%%i"
 DEL "%%i"
 CALL :report "%%~ni instructs ===!instruction!==="
 CALL :execute
)
GOTO loop

:endrun
DEL "%flagdir%\%myname%.run"

GOTO :EOF

:report
ECHO %TIME% %~1
GOTO :eof

:instruct
:: instruct another instance - select destination
SET /a found=0
FOR %%a IN (%othero%) DO SET /a found+=1
SET /a selection=(%RANDOM% %% %found%) + 1
FOR /f "tokens=%selection%" %%a IN ('echo %othero%') DO SET sendto=%%a
SET /a selection=4 + (%RANDOM% %% 8)
SET "line=%1 %selection%"
CALL :report "to %sendto%: %line%"
>"%flagdir%\%myname%.%sendto%" ECHO %line%

GOTO :eof

:: Instructions that may be passed
:count
FOR /l %%z IN (1,1,%1) DO ECHO count...%%z
GOTO :eof
:repeat
FOR /l %%z IN (1,1,%1) DO ECHO repeat...%1
GOTO :eof

:execute
CALL :%instruction%
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a way...

Starting with an empty directory (U:\comm), you can `start` any number of instances of the batch, each with a unique name as its first parameter.

Establish a file called *instancename.run* to flag that a routine is running.

The caper with "randmod" is designed to modify the return of `%random%` by recording the hundredths-of-a-second. Two batch files starting at "the same" time will generate the same sequence of random numbers, but the hundredths-of-a-second will likely be different. To supplement this, I'd invoke the above as

```
start thisbatch fred&ping -n 3 127.0.0.1&start thisbatch derf&ping -n 3 127.0.0.1&start thisbatch blue&ping -n 3 127.0.0.1&start thisbatch pink
```

In a loop controlled by the `ping` timeout, we then see whether the flagfile "quit" exists and if it does, delete the `instancename.run` file (and quit)

Otherwise, look for other names that are running (*.run files) and set `others` to a list of those instancenames. If it changes from the previous version, report the change (this is solely for demo purposes, of course.)

Then select a random number 0..99, modifying the returned random to get over synchronisation (it's quick and dirty for a demonstration. Doesn't need to be exact...)

If the chosen number is 37 then send a "count" insruction to another instance, else if it's 51, send a "repeat" instruction (just for demo - 1% chance of each)

The `instruct` routine chooses a destination from the list of other instances and builds an instruction (count/repeat + a random number) which is recorded in a file called *thisinstancename.destinationinstance*

Then we check to see whether we've received an instruction and if we have, we execute it.

The two routines `count` and `repeat` simply show different things in the destination instance - all for demonstration purposes.

The selection is echoed for security-blanket purposes - showing that the loop's still running and displaying a significant number controlling the destination process.