# Run multiple cmd window and execute command parallely

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

What I need is a batch file when opened, it should execute `webpack -w` command in 3 different folders in 3 different cmd window

What I tried

```
start
cd P:\localFolder\FolderA
webpack -w


start
cd P:\localFolder\FolderB
webpack -w

start
cd P:\localFolder\FolderC
webpack -w
```

This will navigate to first folder and executes the `webpack -w` command and opens one more command window(without changing to specified directory)

Comment: see: `start /?` (and `cd /?`, there is a `/d` switch`)

Comment: sorry I am new in writing a batch file, can u pls explain ? what change to make ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally the shorter first

```
start /d P:\localFolder\FolderA webpack -w
start /d P:\localFolder\FolderB webpack -w
start /d P:\localFolder\FolderC webpack -w
```

to run asynchronously the command should be passed to start

```
start cmd /c "cd P:\localFolder\FolderA & webpack -w & pause"
start cmd /c "cd P:\localFolder\FolderB & webpack -w & pause"
start cmd /c "cd P:\localFolder\FolderC & webpack -w & pause"
```

`&` is the command delimiter

EDIT after comment and, the first `&` can be changed to `&&`, to avoid doing the second command if the first fails

```
start cmd /c "cd /d P:\localFolder\FolderA && webpack -w & pause"
start cmd /c "cd /d P:\localFolder\FolderB && webpack -w & pause"
start cmd /c "cd /d P:\localFolder\FolderC && webpack -w & pause"
```

the last `& pause` is just to see the output after execution

for documentation use autodocumented commands in a cmd

```
start /?
```

Comment: You might also need `cd /d` if you are not already on the P: drive.

Comment: you can also use `start /d` switch to set the folder.

Comment: This is a nice way to do it but there is another way to do this easier while preserving the cmd windows for the potential next commands you wanna run on multiple prompts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305151/how-to-make-two-running-command-prompt-windows-send-commands-to-each-other-on-th/35034923#35034923